# What Java 2D library should I choose for meshing?

Tags: processing, java-2d

I have read many posts and intros about various Java graphics libs, but couldn't find out which one best suits my needs. What I have to do is make some simple visualising panel with dynamic pan and zoom options, that will be able to render 2D mesh consisting of several ten thousands 4-node elements. So, there will be max 50000 nodes, same number of node markers and labels, ~ little less number of element labels and, if optimised, little more than 2 times of lines (i.e >100000 lines).

My favorites are Processing, Piccolo2D, G, but I'm not sure if they are appropriate for my project.

What are your opinions and advices?

Answer (score 0):

I've used processing to make some rather large visualizations. One nice feature is that you can let OpenGL handle the rendering, which speeds it up tremendously. All you have to do is import processing.opengl.*;